# Multithreaded wordcount program in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, race-condition

I'm currently working on a C++ wordcount program, but currently I am stuck.
It works when I just use one Thread, but doesn't if I increase the amount of Threads I want to use. When I start the program I give it the the amount of Threads I want to use and also a file Path which I want to read.

In this part of the code I initialize the threads.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
    input.push_back(map<string, info>()) ;
    jobInfo tmp;
    tmp.id = i;
    tmp.job = thread(counterino, filePath, numberOfThreads, tmp.id, &input[i]);
    jobs.push_back(move(tmp));
}
```

As you can see I give every thread its own reference to a map, which I do because I want to avoid race conditions(also I want to reduce the maps to just one map when all threads finish). The struct info contains the amount of the words appearance and in which line it appears. So far so good, this part of the code works as expected.

This part of the code is supposed to read the words in the text file and save it in the map reference I passed over to it. This also works as aspected, but only when the amount of threads I want to use is exactly one.

If I use more then one thread it doesn't save anything in any of the maps and that's the part I don't get.

```
while (file >> word) {
    //cout << word << "   " << threadId << endl;
    if (file.peek() == '\n'){
        line++;
    }
    tmp = input->operator[](word);
    tmp.word = word;
    tmp.numberOfOccurences += 1;

    tmp.lineOfOccurence.push_back(line);

    input->operator[](word) = tmp;
}
```

Comment: you're using input.push_back( ... ) and later on using &input[i] which may render Undefined Behaviour (depending on if haven't used input.reserve) since push_back (in the next loop iteration) usually invalidates iterators into input.

Comment: what is `input`?

Comment: input is a vector of maps<string, info>.

So should I use &input.at(i)? Anyway I'll read into vector.reserve();